# Python 3 get HTML content

Tags: python, lxml

I'm using this code to get the web site html content,

```
import urllib.request
import lxml.html as lh
req= urllib.request.Request("http://www.ip-adress.com/ip_tracer/157.123.22.11", 
headers={'User-Agent' : "Magic Browser"})
html = urllib.request.urlopen(req).read()
doc = lh.fromstring(html)
print (''.join(doc.xpath('.//*[@class="odd"]')[-1].text_content().split()))
```

I want to get the Organization:  Zenith Data Systems.
but it shows some errors

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/python3.2.3/lib/python3.2/urllib/request.py", line 1135, in do_open
h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers)
File "/usr/local/python3.2.3/lib/python3.2/http/client.py", line 967, in request
self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
File "/usr/local/python3.2.3/lib/python3.2/http/client.py", line 1005, in _send_request
self.endheaders(body)
File "/usr/local/python3.2.3/lib/python3.2/http/client.py", line 963, in endheaders
self._send_output(message_body)
File "/usr/local/python3.2.3/lib/python3.2/http/client.py", line 808, in _send_output
self.send(msg)
File "/usr/local/python3.2.3/lib/python3.2/http/client.py", line 746, in send
self.connect()
File "/usr/local/python3.2.3/lib/python3.2/http/client.py", line 724, in connect
self.timeout, self.source_address)
File "/usr/local/python3.2.3/lib/python3.2/socket.py", line 404, in create_connection
raise err
File "/usr/local/python3.2.3/lib/python3.2/socket.py", line 395, in create_connection
sock.connect(sa)
socket.error: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "ext.py", line 4, in <module>
html = urllib.request.urlopen(req).read()
File "/usr/local/python3.2.3/lib/python3.2/urllib/request.py", line 138, in urlopen
return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
File "/usr/local/python3.2.3/lib/python3.2/urllib/request.py", line 369, in open
response = self._open(req, data)
File "/usr/local/python3.2.3/lib/python3.2/urllib/request.py", line 387, in _open
'_open', req)
File "/usr/local/python3.2.3/lib/python3.2/urllib/request.py", line 347, in _call_chain
result = func(*args)
File "/usr/local/python3.2.3/lib/python3.2/urllib/request.py", line 1155, in http_open
return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPConnection, req)
File "/usr/local/python3.2.3/lib/python3.2/urllib/request.py", line 1138, in do_open
raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 111] Connection refused>}
```

How to solve it. Thanks,

Comment: `KeyboardInterrupt` means that you pressed `CTRL-C` and stopped the process.

Comment: @Blender: Thanks, i have already change the error

Comment: Can you access the site using a browser/or via proxy? Do you have a firewall? Your ip might be banned.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, Connection Refused means only registered users are allowed to access the page, or server under heavy maintenance or similar reasons.

From your above code, if you want to handle errors you may try using try and except like below code:

```
try:
    req= urllib.request.Request("http://www.ip-adress.com/ip_tracer/157.123.22.11",headers={'User-Agent' : "Magic Browser"})
    html = urllib.request.urlopen(req).read()
    doc = lh.fromstring(html)
    print (''.join(doc.xpath('.//*[@class="odd"]')[-1].text_content().split()))
except urllib.error.URLError as e:
    print(e.reason)
```